# Can spells be supercharged for free with Soulfire's new mechanics?

Tags: spells, magic, dresden-files

Since the release of the Paranet Papers and the changes to Soulfire, I have a question.

According to YS288 it says

> In addition, if you already practice evocation, you may use a sponsored power source to “supercharge” an element you've already specialized in.

but in PP under "The Mechanics of Soulfire" it doesn't say anything about being able to supercharge spells. I don't know what to do and my GM is stuck as well.

**So does the Soul stress track replace sponsor debt or must you use a Soul stress for every spell that you cast that incorporates Soulfire?**

Answer (score 6):

## Preface

There were some general changes to Sponsored Magic made in the Paranet Papers in order to better reflect the books. Most telling is that they changed sponsored magic debt to be usable for basically anything. Extra shifts, fate points, to absorb consequences, it is really easy to get debt now.

## Answer

In Paranet Papers the specifics of Soulfire as sponsored magic get laid out in more detail to match the books. So lets step through what they can do one bit at a time.

**First** we have partially satisfying the Catch

Sponsored: Treat the enemy as one level less potent in toughness abilities if they are opposed to your sponsor (summer/winter courts)

Soulfire: Counts at catch for any Holy or Divine weaknesses (not partial but fully satisfying catch). Always grants the one level less potent toughness abilites for ANY enemy (not just ones opposed to your "sponsor").

**Second** we have expanded abilities

Sponsored: Thaumaturgy at Evocation speed. Enhanced abilities (summers healing) without the knowledge checks.

Soulfire: +1 bonus to power or complexity on any thaumaturgy dealing with direct creation of something (illusion, veils, ward, items)

**Third** we have "supercharged" evocation

Sponsored: The big ticket here is that you can use your existing specializations and make them even better. You can combine theme effects: demonic patron + fire spell = hellfire

Soulfire: +1 bonus to power or complexity on any evocation dealing with direct creation of something. So "supercharged" fire might get +1 power if you are throwing up a wall of flame.

**Fourth** we have "sponsor debt"

Sponsored: You can use power from your sponsor at no immediate cost to you in a pinch but you incur a debt point to fill a gap. (Note this expanded to things not related to your sponsor now)

Soulfire: You don't have an external power source. While similar to sponsored magic in how it can be used you instead use the soul track. This line in PP is the key "The soul stress track replaces the sponsor for all practical intents and purposes"